# Problema al bindear un label en xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo un problema al intentar bindear diferentes datos a labels en una vista.

Yo tengo la vista

> CobroPendiente.xaml

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="SGesRepartidores.Vistas.CobroPendiente"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
Title="Cobro Pendiente">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid Padding="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Numero de Factura:" />
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="{Binding NROFAC}" />
```

El cual es llamado desde la clase:

> Cobro.cs

```
public class Cobro : Controlador//FCOBROS
{

    public Command btnPendienteCobro { get; set; }

    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public int? IDC { get; set; }
    public int? CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string SERIE { get; set; }
    public string FECHA { get; set; }
    public int? NROFAC { get; set; }
    public string TIPO { get; set; }
    public float? IMPORTE { get; set; }
    public string VENCI { get; set; }
    public int? NROREC { get; set; }
    public float? IMPCOB { get; set; }
    public string FECHACOB { get; set; }
    public int? FORMACOB { get; set; }
    public float? PENDCOB { get; set; }
    public string AGENTE { get; set; }




    public Cobro() { }
    public Cobro(Dictionary<string, object> q)
    {
        this.IDC = int.Parse(q["IDC"].ToString());
        this.CLIENTE = int.Parse(q["CLIENTE"].ToString());
        this.SERIE = q["SERIE"] as string;
        this.FECHA = q["FECHA"] as string;
        this.NROFAC = int.Parse(q["NROFAC"].ToString());
        this.TIPO = q["TIPO"] as string;
        this.IMPORTE = float.Parse(q["IMPORTE"].ToString());
        this.VENCI = q["VENCI"] as string;
        this.NROREC = null; //int.Parse(q["NROREC"].ToString());
        this.IMPCOB = null;//float.Parse(q["IMPCOB"].ToString());
        this.FECHACOB = null;// q["FECHA_COB"] as string;
        this.FORMACOB = null; // int.Parse(q["FORMACOB"].ToString());
        this.PENDCOB = float.Parse(q["PENDCOB"].ToString());
        this.AGENTE = q["AGENTE"] as string;

        btnPendienteCobro = new Command(PendienteCobro);

    }

    public void PendienteCobro()
    {
        this.Unico(async () =>
        {
            Utils.UIHandler.NavPush(new CobroPendiente(this));
        });
    }
```

Este boton que llama a la vista CobroPendiente es llamado en la vista `DatosPago.xaml` que es un conjunto de una lista de Objetos de `Cobro`

Cuando llamo a `CobroPendiente.xaml.cs` nos manda al controlador ->

```
public partial class CobroPendiente : ContentPage
{

    private Controladores.CobroPendienteController controlador;
    private Modelos.Lite.Cabecera cabecera;
    private Modelos.Lite.Cobro cobro;

    public CobroPendiente (Modelos.Lite.Cobro cobro )
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.controlador = new Controladores.CobroPendienteController(cobro);
```

Donde el controlador `CobroPendienteController` ->

```
public class CobroPendienteController : Controlador
{
    public Modelos.Lite.Cobro cobro { get; set; }


    public CobroPendienteController(Modelos.Lite.Cobro cobro)
    {
        this.cobro = cobro;

    }
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicación, cuando cargo la Vista CobroPendiente me da el error con el binding:

> Binding: 'NROFAC' property not found on 'Controladores.CobroPendienteController', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Agradecería cualquier consejo para entender el porqué de este fallo.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Según la respuesta más votada de [esta pregunta:binding expression error property not found on object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274255/binding-expression-error-property-not-found-on-object) los miembros que bindees deben ser sí o sí públicos.

He buscado el por qué de esto y he llegado a [este foro de microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6f04c11-1511-4440-a27d-75307741f7fc/why-property-must-be-public-if-it-is-used-in-xaml-binding?forum=wpf) donde mencionan lo siguiente:

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

Por lo que tu fallo podría estar en definir CobroPendiente con atributos privados **que no son accesibles** para propósitos de binding.

Prueba estableciendo los miembros como públicos en tu clase CobroPendiente de la siguiente manera:

```
public Controladores.CobroPendienteController { get; set; }
public Modelos.Lite.Cabecera cabecera { get; set; }
public Modelos.Lite.Cobro cobro { get; set; }
```

o si no quieres que se pueda modificar el valor de los atributos, únicamente con `{get;}`